# Rails simulate ActionMailer send fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

I have `ActionJob` which sends some mails, rescues if it would fail and updates database record, of course I want to write some specs for this job, but I'm very confused how to test it. Does it possible to simulate mail send fail or any ideas how I test my job?

Comment: who do you use as a mailer service?  Sendgrid?

Comment: Yes I use sendgrid

Comment: Take a look at the Rails tutorial at the link below. It discusses creation and testing of Action Mailers, although it does not specifically discuss ActionJob

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#sec-email_previews

Comment: Checkout the docs for webhooks:   https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html     Use these to determine if it fails on their side and then rescues in your code will handle errors on your side.

Comment: @bkunzi01 is it good idea to use real mailer in test environment?

Comment: @CaptainChaos thank you for your reply, I know how to test mailers, my problem is that i want to simulate mailer fail

Answer (score 0):

You should use stubbing or mocking. It's typical approach.

For simulate mail send fail with gem 'rr':

stub(AccountsMailer.welcome).deliver_later { raise 'my error' }

Comment: Can you please provide some examples?